# Java -Display image that retrieved from DB in browser

Tags: java, jsp

I save images in db as blobs and I want to retrieve an image and display it in browser in jsp file. 
How I implement it in Java ? 
Thanks

Comment: have u try something or search on google ?

Comment: if you want the jsp code or db code.

Answer (score 0):

try this method and solve your doubts.

```
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT col_blob FROM mysql_all_table");

    if (rs.next()) {
      Blob blob = rs.getBlob("col_blob");
      long blobLength = blob.length();

      int pos = 1; // position is 1-based
      int len = 10;
      byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(pos, len);

      InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
      int b = is.read();
```

another example to[just goto this link](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/03/insert-and-retrieve-images-from-mysql.html)

listen to me, if you had any doubt you should must give me comments.

Comment: Thanks,The retrieve from db is clear , How I display it in Jsp ?

Comment: if you want to display the image in web page.

Comment: Yes.I want to display it in web page

Comment: @liron, stack flow is not allow to ask the same post in different type of question, because this post will be going to see the future users(doubt). so, that only I've not posting the answer. but, this first and last to answer your question, because your new user that only, just goto this site and display the image, **http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/884256-how-display-more-image-database-using-jsp**.